# C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Threading.Tasks.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references

Tags: asp.net, windows, visual-studio-2015

Hi when i build my project i get following error

Error        'C:\WS2013\Internet\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.1.1.10\lib\net40\System.Threading.Tasks.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Threading.Tasks.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.   Portal.Web  C:\WS2013\Internet\Portal.Web\CSC

i am running vs 2015 on windows 10 machine

Comment: If you target .NET 4.5+ remove the BCL package. It's only needed to add `async/await` support to .NET 4.0 projects

Answer (score 0):

Unload the project, open the csproj file and remove the references by hand (remove package)

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Threading.Tasks">
  <HintPath>...... Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

@Edit
Remove Microsoft.BCL package

Comment: That would be the *wrong* thing to do.  The package that must be removed is Microsoft.BCL